# Using FFprobe in Python

Tags: python, csv, ffmpeg, ffprobe

How can I use FFprobe in python scripts, which also exports the output as csv file?

The command I want to perform is:

```
ffprobe -i file_name -show_frames -select_streams v:1 -print_format csv > filename.csv
```

I looked at other posts about similar problem, and changed a little:

```
def probe_file(filename):
    cmnd = ['ffprobe', '-i',filename, '-show_frames', '-select_streams', 'a', '-print_format', 'csv']
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmnd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print filename
    out, err =  p.communicate()
    print "==========output=========="
    print out
    if err:
        print "========= error =r======="
        print err
```

however, I can't seem to have "> filename.csv" working.

After analysing the video, I want all the output as csv file, named the same as the file name

Does anyone know how I can approach this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the data available to python (as a list of lists):

```
data = [l.split(',') for l in out.decode('ascii').splitlines()]
```

If you just want to dump the data to a file:

```
with open("{}.csv".format(filename), "w") as f:
    f.write(out.decode('ascii'))
```

Note that I'm using Python 3, hence the `decode()`s (`out` is `bytes`, and must be decoded).  You're clearly using Python 2, so the `decode()`s probably aren't necessary.